# How would one install one service for multiple applications on Android?

Tags: android, android-service, apk

I have one application that is branded for multiple customers so user might install two or more on his android device. The application uses a service to communicate with server back-end. What I would like to do is have only one instance of service and multiple applications. To do this right now I need to install one apk for service and one for each application.

Is there a way to just install one apk?

Or is there a way to make applications "depended" on each other?

Comment: "Or is there a way to make applications "depended" on each other?" -- that is not generally a good idea. What happens if the user uninstalls an app that the other apps depend upon? I would focus instead on keeping the services out of memory as much as possible (e.g., do transactions with an `IntentService`), and then not worry about having individual copies of the service per app.

Comment: That would not work. The whole idea is that we have this one background service that "caches" some values which are consumed by "front-end" applications. The data CAN NOT be saved and we can not use internet connection at the moment the information is required eg the data is retrieved once a day and should be keep by service in memory (yes I know things can happen to service but that is my problem to solve).

Comment: did you figured out a way? I was thinking of all the applications starting the instance of their Service but in its own global process, so if one of the app already started the Service, the other copy will not be started anymore...

Comment: Sadly I did not find any "smart" solution. Currently I just pack the service with every application...